# Azure Service Bus Queue ReceiveBatch for PHP client

Tags: php, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

Is PHP azure bus client library supports ReceiveBatch API? As per the client library, we have only receiveMessage(Brokered messages ) and receiveQueueMessage.

Comment: From the [offcial doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php), it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look of this offcial doc:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php

From this document you can see all the features (in case of using php sdk), from the documentation description, ReceiveBatch is not supported in PHP sdk.

If you use .net sdk, then it is supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.receivebatch?view=azure-dotnet